# Am facing issue in 1st time refresh the crome in homepage alert popup is not showing - in angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

1st thing thank u for ur response fr my last question

Now am facing issue - while am landing the homepage  for the 1st time this alert pop up is not working if i moved inside the application it's working fine but 1st time in home page it's not working.
Below is my code

```
@HostListener("window:beforeunload", 
["$event"]) 
unloadHandler(event: Event) {
let result = confirm("Changes 
you made may not be saved.");
if (result) {
  // Do more processing...
}
event.returnValue = false; // 
stay on same page
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I have another solution, Try it once -

First create a guard file called confirmation.guard.ts-

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanDeactivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from 
'@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export interface CanComponentCanDeactivate {
confirm: () => boolean;
}

@Injectable()
export class ConfirmationGuard implements 
CanDeactivate<CanComponentCanDeactivate> {
canDeactivate(
component: CanComponentCanDeactivate,
next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean>| boolean{ 
  return component.confirm();
 }
}
```

Then import ConfirmationGuard in app.module.ts -

```
import { ConfirmationGuard } from './guards/confirmation.guard';
@NgModule({
 providers: [ConfirmationGuard]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In your routing module file where your component routing defined -
use this ConfirmationGuard on which component you want to show alert popup -

```
   import { ConfirmationGuard } from './guards/confirmation.guard';

   const routes: Routes = [
   { path: 'your-path', component: YourComponent, canDeactivate: 
   [ConfirmationGuard] },
   ];

  @NgModule({
  providers: [ConfirmationGuard ],
  imports: [],
  exports: [RouterModule]
 })
 export class YourRoutingModule { }
```

Then implements CanComponentCanDeactivate in which component you want to show popup -

```
import { CanComponentCanDeactivate } from '../../../guards/confirmation.guard';
 
 export class YourComponent implements CanComponentCanDeactivate {
 successRedirect: boolean = false;

 //call confirm() function which have created in guard file
 confirm() {
   if (!this.successRedirect) {
     return confirm("Are you sure you want to navigate away ?")
   }
   else{
      return true;
   }
 }
}
```

I hope it will be helpful.